# Autohotkey, how to define window-version sensitive hotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I try to define <kbd>Win+1</kbd> to launch some application on Windows XP, but don't want such behavior on Win7+. How can I do that?

The following snippet will cause Windows 7 to show "Trigger on Win 5.x" box as well. What's going wrong?

```
#If, A_OSVersion in WIN_2003, WIN_XP, WIN_2000
#1::
    MsgBox Trigger on Win 5.x
return
#If
```

Autohotkey version 1.1.13.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. Autohotkey's `#If` doc presents examples that the condition can be a function, so the following code works:

```
IsWin5x()
{
    if A_OSVersion in WIN_2003,WIN_XP,WIN_2000
    {
        return 1
    }
    else
    {
        return 0
    }
}

#If IsWin5x()
#1::
    MsgBox Trigger on Win 5.x
return
#If
```

<kbd>Win+1</kbd> works on WinXP and <kbd>Win+1</kbd> preserves its original functionality on Win7.

Comment: Yes this will work.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** `#If [, Expression ]` The operators "between", "is", "in", and "contains" are not supported in expressions.

I changed it to

```
#1::
If A_OSVersion in WIN_2003,WIN_XP,WIN_2000
    MsgBox Trigger on Win 5.x
return
```

NOTE: No spaces in `WIN_2003,WIN_XP,WIN_2000`

This shows no message box on Windows 7

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, still not what I expect, that will invalidate Win7's native ``Win+1`` functionality.

Comment: You didn't mention this specific requirement!